# Deal with concurrent http requests that depend on each other

Tags: swift, concurrency, nsurlsession

So, I have a complicated data to fetch, which involves 4 requests, each one depending on the result of the last, and some of then returns a list, so for each element on that list, I have to get some info.

**Context**

I'm working with YouTube API and the data I have to get is a list of the latest videos sent by the user's subscribed channels.

Here's the requests necessary to do this:

- GET /subscriptions/list [1]
- GET /channels/list [2]
- GET /playlistItems/list [3]
- GET /videos [4]

[1]: Returns a list of the user's subscribed channels. The return size is configured to 5, so I have to repeat this request until all subscribed channels have been fetched

[2]: Returns the id of the sent videos playlist for a specific channel

[3]: Returns n last videos of specific channel

[4]: Returns info fo a specific video

**First atempt**

At first, I got the data in a synchronous way, that is, I executed request [1], until all channels had been fetched. Then, I iterated through the channels list, and for each channel, executed request [2] to get the id of the playlist. Then request [3] to get n videos, and for each video, get its info with request [4].

**The problem**

The problem with that is it takes a long time to return the videos to the user, so I thought of executing the request in parallel. The problem with that is that I need to know when all requests have finished to run, to reorder the list of videos by date. And to do that, my code has become a complicated mess of DispatchGroup's everywhere.

So, in short, what's the **best approach to deal with** a problem like this, where I have **various requests that depend on each other**, and I would like to execute some of them **in parallel** (the second one - which I have to do for each channel) and need to know when all have finished.

Comment: Show what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was banging my head around trying to organize this complex request process using `NSURLSession`, and I could not come to the code I wanted.

To make it easier to work with, I used [Just](https://github.com/JustHTTP/Just), which allowed me to execute these requests in a much simpler, clearer and easy way.

Another option would be to wrap `NSURLSession` on a promise using [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit#choose-your-networking-library), which easily allows [chaining of requests](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit/blob/master/Documentation/CommonPatterns.md#chaining).

Answer (score 0):

Use `DispatchGroup`. DispatchGroup is a "component" in iOS that can group some related operations, that must be waited.

Here you can't use it directly, why? Because the URLSession itself posts the web operation on a background thread different than the initiator, so we must `enter` and `leave` manually. When operation count is 0, the `group.wait` returns.

This code is not the best design pattern. But this demonstrates only what can be done in a simple design pattern.

```
import UIKit

class URLRequestGroup {

    var dispatchGroup: DispatchGroup

    init(dispatchGroup: DispatchGroup) {
        self.dispatchGroup = dispatchGroup
    }

    init() {
        self.dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
    }

    func beginURLRequest(urlRequest: URLRequest,
                         completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {

        let urlSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default)
        // Enter the dispatchGroup manually
        dispatchGroup.enter()
        urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { [weak self] data, urlResponse, error in

            completionHandler(data, urlResponse, error)
            // Leave this dispatchGroup.
            self?.dispatchGroup.leave()
        }).resume()

    }

}

let group = URLRequestGroup()
group.beginURLRequest(urlRequest: URLRequest(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "http://www.example.com")), completionHandler: { data, urlResponse, error in

    print(data?.count ?? 0)
})
// Put any other request here.
group.dispatchGroup.wait()
```

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't figure out a way to easily organize the requests using this approach. Now I'm trying to use [Just](https://github.com/JustHTTP/Just) to hide some of URLSession complexity, and mix it's synchronous/assynchronous modes of operation. It seems that the code is getting easier to work with... I'll post here the results later.

Comment: What is difficult in this approach? Just 1. create a DispatchGroup, 2. When initializing a request, use dispatchGroup.enter(), 3. When the request ends or makes an error, use dispatchGroup.leave(). That is all.

Comment: The problem is the number of requests I have to do to get the data I need. And each request depending on the previous one. The way I tried to structure, it became a mess of callbacks to manage.